# Where did golang implementation about builtin function

Tags: go

For example, if I'm printing an interface by calling `print()`, and then, It will call `printiface()`, I'm wondering what does go actually between these two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could gather, `print` calls turn into `printstring`, `printiface`, etc. at compile time. If you want to look at how `print` code is generated, you could be interested in [this code](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/gc/walk.c#1759) in `src/cmd/gc/walk.c`.

Answer (score 1):

That method `printiface()` is mainly called by `ifaceI2T()`, `ifaceI2I()`, `ifaceeq()`, `printinter()`.
So you can see more in [`runtime/iface.c`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/runtime/iface.c?spec=svnfa67019528712542183118fd0af7b3e88d59f20f&r=fa67019528712542183118fd0af7b3e88d59f20f)